# Will GROUP BY run faster if grouped field has a Standard / Custom Index?

Tags: soql, performance, externalid

Would it help to make a field an `External Id` if we use it as a `GROUP BY` field in many LDV SOQL queries?

Is there a order in which `SOQL` queries are processed? So will it group after it filtered? How does selectivity come into account for `AggregateResult` queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Inside the Force.com Query Optimizer Webinar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khXLBunrfJ4) for details, but basically there are several paths that the system can take: filter first by sharing, filter first by index, or full table scan (when sharing is large or wide open and non-indexed fields are filtered). In any case, if you're not filtering correctly, your performance will suffer. The `GROUP BY` clause doesn't affect the number of rows returned directly. Use `LIMIT` to set a limit (and thus increase the likelihood of meeting selectivity) and an `ORDER BY` that is indexed. You can `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` the same field, in which case, indexing the field would increase the likelihood of selectivity and decrease query execution time.

Comment: I just watched this seminar and it did not answer my question whether an index will affect the performance of a GROUP BY or NOT. And - sorry to day that - so doesn't your answer.

Comment: I apologize that my answer was unclear. Oracle's GROUP BY statement can benefit from indexes in very specific scenarios, and it's entirely possible that it will occasionally be used, but the answer is at best, "maybe", since salesforce.com overrides the default query plan optimizer with their own patented version. The actual gains would be dependent on who ran the query, the sharing model of the organization, and the number of potential records involved. Your biggest gains will be from proper filtering, using ORDER BY on indexed fields, and using LIMIT.

Comment: The presentation that I linked to is probably the most comprehensive optimization guide I've seen to date from salesforce.com. The fact that they decided to outline sharing, profile permissions, ORDER BY, and LIMIT as opposed to GROUP BY suggests that the gains from an index would be negligible or non-existent. Salesforce.com is well known for excluding information to questions like this, usually because the answer is uncertain or they simply don't feel like saying anything.